# call function dynamically, passing arguments from variable

Tags: php, function, dynamic

here is my ajax_handle file:

```
   if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] !== "XMLHttpRequest") 
    {
        echo "Error"; 
        exit();

    }
    $req = explode("_",$_POST['req']);
    $className = $req[0] . "Controller" ;
    $methodName = $req[1];
    $file = "application/controllers/" . $className . ".php" ;
    require_once $file;
    if ($_POST['data']) {
        var_dump($_POST['data']);
    }
    $controller = new $className;
    $result = $controller->$methodName();
    echo json_encode($result);
```

I send the arguments as any array in the $_POST['data'] variable. i have no idea what would be the best way to pass them to the (dynamic) $methodName function.

Comment: I do not like the security problems with your code. I can probably require any file in the filesystem that ends with "Controller.php" by simply sending `"../../WhateverPath/Any_xxx"` in `$_POST['req']`. I can call ANY public method in the controller. Do check that the required file really is inside the path you think. Use `realpath()` to expand any relative path you might get, or forbid those characters entirely that might be "file path" relevant. Is there a reason the controller name can be ANY character on this planet? ASCII letters should be enough.

Comment: @Sven thank u for pointing this out, but how would you send an altered $_POST['req'] in an ajax call? Anyway im gonna make an ASCII filter or an allowed filnames array.

Comment: There is nothing that keeps me from sending a HTTP request to your server. And all the data inside is under my control. You might be able to obfuscate stuff, but I can always look at your ajax code to see what you are doing, do the same and then alter things to check for interesting behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could just pass `$_POST['data']` as is to your dynamic method. You can have the 
dynamic method accept the array but initially set default values so you can easily handle and 
validate them. Example:

```
class AController
{
  public function dynamicMethod($params)
  {
    // Set default values but allow them to be overridden by $params
    $locals = array_merge(array(
      'name' => 'John Doe',
      'address' => 'Nowhere',
    ), $params);

    // Do stuffs and return result. Example:
    return array('nameAndAddress' => $locals['name'] . ' lives at ' . $locals['address']);
  }
}
```

You also opt to use [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to convert the 
`name` and `address` above into real local variables.

In your ajax handle:

```
$controller = new $className;
$result = $controller->$methodName($_POST['data']);
echo json_encode($result);
```

With all these said, please note that what @Sven is saying is correct. There are some security 
issues in your current approach.

Comment: thanks Shiki! I found this solution call_user_func_array(array($controller, $methodName),$_POST['data'] )