# Ajax handling - securty issues

Tags: php, security

In my earlier post [call function dynamically, passing arguments from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842359/call-function-dynamically-passing-arguments-from-variable) Sven pointed out that my code is vulnerable against Local File Inclusion. I made some modification to prevent LFI. Is it enough or should i  be worried?

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] !== "XMLHttpRequest") 
    {
        echo "Error"; 
        exit();

    }
    $req = explode("_",$_POST['req']);
    /*
      User input should always be escaped 
      using preg_quote before being used in a regexp pattern.
      Thanks bwoebi 
    */
    $className = preg_quote($req[0]) . "Controller" ;
    $methodName = $req[1];
    $args= isset($_POST["data"]) ? $_POST['data'] : array();


    $file = "application/controllers/" . $className . ".php" ;

    if (!file_exists($file) || preg_match("/^[a-z]$/", strtolower($className)))
        exit();

    require_once $file;

    $controller = new $className;
    $result = call_user_func_array(array($controller, $methodName),$args );

    echo json_encode($result);
```

Another issue could be that users can call any controller file's public method from the folder.
But as i know more Frameworks are using in their routing the domain.xy/controller/method/par pattern, which has the same risk. (Although in my controllers i use as many server side validation as possible)

I thinking about to put some authentication into the ajax handler /router file.

```
// PSEUDO CODE

$user = new User();
// maybe bad practice to store the id session after authentication. Any comment on this?
$userGroup =$user->getUserGroupById($_SESSION["user"]);

$security = new Security();
$whiteList = $security->getWhiteList($userGroup);
//$whiteList is an array with the list of controllers the user may access 
if (!in_array(className, $whiteList ))
 exit();
```

Any comments, best practice example are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

It should be now secure as you don't allow malicious points and NUL-Bytes to be included with the regex.

But still it isn't good practice. You really should match it against your whitelist. It is, as you say secure and only allows the user to choose the controllers you allow the user to choose.

tl;dr: Use what you wrote in your pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, your code looks like a mess.

- You're *not* using `$className` in a regexp pattern, so why are you trying to escape it with [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote)?
- Why are you *first* checking whether the class file exists and only *then* whether the class name is even allowed?  That seems backwards to me.  (In this case, it shouldn't do any actual harm, but it's good practice to do input validation *first* before using the input for *anything*.)
- Isn't your invalid classname check backwards anyway?  Your

  ```
  preg_match("/^[a-z]$/", strtolower($className))
  ```

  will return true only if `$className` consists only of letters.  (Also, using `strtolower()` is a pretty inefficient way to do case-insensitive matching.)  Shouldn't it be

  ```
  !preg_match('/^[a-z]$/i', $className)
  ```

  or even

  ```
  preg_match('/[^a-z]/i', $className)
  ```

  instead?

If you fixed all those things, your code *might* be OK (assuming you didn't introduce any new bugs while doing so).

You could test it by, say, creating a file named `application/BogusController.php` and seeing if you can include it by passing `../Bogus` as the class name.  Try to think of other possible variations too, and test them.

In any case, like bwoebi notes, your pseudocode uses a lot more secure approach and should be harder to get wrong.  I'd also suggest you go with it.